# Why isn't printf() in PHP working when I use double quotation marks?

Tags: php, wordpress, printf

`printf("by %1$s on %2$s", 'string1', 'string2');` doesn't work, whereas `printf('by %1$s on %2$s', 'string1', 'string2');` does.

I'm actually designing a Wordpress theme, and following the original twentyten theme very closely. The weird thing is, I've been using double quotation marks on all my previous printf() statements without any problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because when you are using double quotes the `$s` is treated as a variable

As in:

```
$x = "World";
echo "Hello $x"; // Will print: "Hello World
```

where as when using:

```
$x = "World";
echo 'Hello $x'; // Will just print "Hello $x"
```

For a more detailed explanation you can check the manual:

[Strings in General](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string)

[Single quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) vs [Double quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: @fterh you should mark this answer as correct if it helped you (the big green arrow on the left of it) .

Answer (score 3):

It is very important to realize php is treating single quoted and double quoted strings differently.

You can read more in official [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), but let me give you a highlight:

```
$t = 'bla';
echo '$t';
```

will output $t, where

```
$t = 'bla';
echo "$t";
```

will output bla

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have the  '$s' bit in your string. When using double quotation marks PHP interprets it as a variable and tries to parse it. You probably used double quotations without the `$` in it earlier.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers say, it treats `$s` as a variable, you could always escape the `$`

```
printf("by %1\$s on %2\$s", 'string1', 'string2');
```

I would however use single quotation marks, as php doesn't need to parse the string and is therefore faster.

Comment: PHP will parse the string even with single quotation marks because (1) it needs to scan for the end of the string and (2) it's looking for escape sequence `\'` which does not end the string. As a result, the speed difference is close to zero (modulo possible bugs in the implementation, with ancient PHP versions this did make a difference).